# Serializing And Deserializing With newsoft.json

Tags: c#, json

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "ItemList":
    [
        "Name":"Assassin's Creed",
        "Name":"Assassin's Creed"
    ]
}
```

And I want to write in the names in the console, so I did this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
var games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemList>(json);
Console.WriteLine(games);

public class ItemList
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And its giving me this output:

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: It still isn't really clear what your current output is

Answer (score 0):

Games is a collection. You should iterate over the items in the collection and print those to the console.

```
var item = new ItemList
{
    Name = "Assassin's Creed"
};
List<ItemList> items = new List<ItemList>
{
    item,
    item
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
List<ItemList> games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemList>>(serialized);

// Incorrect output
Console.WriteLine(games);

// Correct output
foreach(ItemList game in games)
{
    Console.WriteLine(game.Name);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The items are from an url it is always changing

Comment: The point is that you cannot print the list directly, but you have to iterate over the collection. The part where it says **// Correct output** is what you should focus on.